# Multiple Vue components inside Main component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the correct way to dynamically insert any number of sub components inside the main 'wrapper' component?

Something like this:

Main Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <GridContainer v-for="item in items">
        <GridItem />
    </GridContainer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { GridContainer, GridItem } from 'Grid';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    GridContainer,
    GridItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
        items: [...array if items that are dynamic]
    };
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `v-for` on the component, not the wrapper. Like this

Your IDE may also warn you that you're missing a key, easiest way to add key is to use index (but it comes with some caveats). Also, you probably want to pass the items into the component. If you have a prop called `item`, you'd pass it with `:item="item"`

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <GridContainer>
        <GridItem  v-for="(item, k) in items" :key="k" :item="item"/>
    </GridContainer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { GridContainer, GridItem } from 'Grid';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    GridContainer,
    GridItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
        items: [...array if items that are dynamic]
    };
  };
}
</script>
```

Comment: One thing that i DID have to do was in the container, put a `<slot />` component so the child component could be placed into the slot.